# Finding the angle of roll of a flying object

Tags: aerodynamics

I'm trying to put together a simple physics engine (with C++ and OpenGL) to simulate the flying of an object.

I've managed to make the object properly yaw so far but I'm having trouble finding out how to make it roll, how to calculate the angle of roll.

I know the heading vector, the steering force, velocity, acceleration and position of the object, along with the desired destination. Should I be able to calculate what I need based on these, and if yes, how?

Frist I thougth if I find the leaning angle, similar in cycle dynamics, I would get the same results but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me plug [*one of my favorite e-books*](https://www.av8n.com/how/).

Then, let's assume your flying object works like an airplane.
That is, it has wings that lift up.

The only way it can turn is if it has some side force.
One way to get that is to turn the rudder, which puts the body a little bit sideways to the wind.
A better way is to roll the aircraft down on one side and up on the other.
That means the direction of lift is tilted, so it points partly to one side, and a little bit less in the up direction.
That sideways component of lift is what makes the plane go in a circle.
(It is no different from turning a bicycle.)

You can work out the geometry pretty easily, but it sounded like you wanted an intuitive explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the link and the explanation! The situation is, indeed, much more clearer now, yet I'm still struggling to put together a simple equation to find out the angle of the rotation. I'm sorry if I miss something trivial here.

Comment: I'm trying to let you do the thinking. You need a lateral acceleration, right? The lateral acceleration you get is gravity $g$ times the tangent of your roll angle $\phi$. You have a certain speed vector of forward motion $v$. The lateral acceleration $a$ alters the direction of motion ($dv/dt$) by a certain number of radians per second. (That's turning.) So to make a left turn of one radian (about 57 degrees) in a certain number of seconds, at speed $v$, that tells you $a$, and that tells you the roll angle.

Comment: Correction: make that sine, not tangent. Also, note that the vertical component is the cosine. That means as the angle becomes large, you must apply more lift if you want to maintain altitude. For example if the roll angle is $60^0$ you need to pull $2g$ of lift in order to maintain $1g$ upward. And at that steep angle the lateral acceleration would be $sine(60^0) \times 2g = 1.73g$. So a steep turn is actually like a climb in the horizontal direction. You can feel this in a plane when it is turning toward the runway - you sink deeper in your seat.